# Adding pmd task to build.xml using Ant

Tags: xml, ant, pmd

I am new to Ant.I have created one ant task for generating pmd on the basis of ruleset.xml.Below code is not working, when i do ant pmd..i want to know whether any problem with this code..

- whether toFile should be entire path(D:\Jenkins) or one the basis of root directory itself?
- Can i run pmd task without depending any other task? Will it be a problem?
- Problem showing with ruleset tag like it should be followed by > or /> or attribute element? :

  ```
  <path id="pmd.classpath">
  <fileset dir="/lib/runtime">
   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
   </fileset>
      </path>

  <target name="pmd" depends="init">
  <taskdef name="pmd" classname="net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask" classpathref="pmd.classpath"/>
  <pmd shortFilenames="true">
  <ruleset="/build/ruleset.xml"/>
  <formatter type="xml" toFile="/build/pmd.xml"/>
  <fileset dir="/src">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
  </fileset>
  </pmd>
  </target>
  ```

Please somebody help me regarding this?..I just started only..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What output or error is shown when you execute your pmd target?

Comment: Now the i am getting new error like. Problem: failed to create task or type pmd
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

Comment: Are the PMD jars really to be found at `/lib/runtime` (an absolute path on a unix box)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your paths are absolute: `/lib`, `/build`, `/src`. I suspect that in fact, all these paths should be relative to your project: `lib`, `build`, `src`.

Make sure that the PMD jar are really at the absolute or relative path you use in the path fileset.